# Any collection of subsets of $X$ can serve as a sub-base for a topology

Tags: general-topology, definition

In my lecture notes there is this observation:

"Any collection $S$ whatsoever of subsets of the non-empty set $X$ can serve as sub-basis for a topology on $X$."

So, taking the set $X:=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and an arbitrary collection of subsets:
$S:=\{ \{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{3,4\} \}$

Any topology on $X$ will include the element $X$ (by the definition of topology) and by the definition of sub-base, every element of the topology on $X$ is a union of a set of finite intersections of elements of $S$. However, no such union of finite intersections of elements of $S$ will give me $X$. So how can such a topology be constructed?

Thanks
Tal

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase

Comment: Take the empty intersection $\bigcap_{A\in\emptyset}A$. This is defined as the underlying set. Intuitively, the more sets intersect, the smaller the resulting set becomes. So if you intersect not a single set, then you get just everything. So this definition makes sense.

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309986/a-possible-vacuous-logical-implication-in-topology).

Answer (score 5):

The intersection of a family of subsets $\{E_j: j\in J\}$ of some set $X$ is defined as 
$$\bigcap_{j\in J}E_j= \{x\in X: \forall j\in J\ \ x\in E_j \} \tag1$$
If the index set $J$ is empty, the condition $\forall j\in J \dots$ is vacuously true, and (1) simplifies to 
$$\bigcap_{j\in \varnothing}E_j= \{x\in X\} =X$$